# Find sequences of fixed-size subsets so that elements repeat only after at least T members

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

Suppose I have a set S with $N$ elements, $S = \{1,2, ..., N\}$.

Let $S^M$ be the set of all subsets of S with size M, with generic element $s^M$. ($S^M$ has of course $\binom{N}{M}$ elements).

I am interested in orderings of $S^M$ with the following property:

Any element that appears in the $i$th subset, $s_i^M$, must *not* reappear in the next $T$ subsets, where $T$ is a given natural number.

Formally, $e \in s^M_i \, \,\rightarrow \, \, e \notin \cup_{t=1}^T s_{i+t}^M $

(Of course, the existence of such sequences is not guaranteed for arbitrary $(M,N,T)$).

I am interested in the fowllowing questions:

1. Is there a way to check for a given triplet (M,N,T) whether such sequences exist?
2. If so, can one also compute the number of existing sequences? (either with or without permutations of the basic elements of $S$.)
3. Given  some $M,T$, what is the minimum $N$ such that at least one sequence exists?
4. Is there a straightforward way to generate one/some/all such subsequences?

I would also generally be happy about any pointers regarding fruitful ways to (re-)formalize the problem, which mathematical fields have appropriate tools or something like this.

(Excuse my likely imprecisions, I'm a layman in terms of mathematics. The last question was meant to ask whether there is a reformulation of the problem in terms of e.g. graph theory, ... , which could be helpful.)

Comment: You need $N \ge M(T+1)+1$ because an element in the first set is prohibited from the next $T$ so you need $T+1$ disjoint subsets and if you don't have a spare the $T+2^{nd}$ subset has to be the same as the first.  This does not apply for $M=1$ because no element reappears at all, you just list the $N$ singletons and are done.  There is then enough flexibility that I suspect you can always find a list, but don't have a nice construction to prove it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

> **This is not a definitive answer, but also way too long for a comment.**

It takes at least $\left\lceil \frac{N}M\right\rceil$ sets for all elements to appear at least once.
Each element appears on $\binom{N-1}{M-1}$ subsets, and these subsets must be $T$ apart from each other.
Therefore, we must have

$$
\left(\left\lceil \frac{N}M\right\rceil-1\right)+\binom{N-1}{M-1}+T\cdot\left[\binom{N-1}{M-1}-1\right]\leq \binom{N}M,$$

which one can rearrange into

$$T\leq\frac{\left(\frac{N}M-1\right)\binom{N-1}{M-1}\,-\,\left(\left\lceil \frac{N}M\right\rceil-1\right)}{\binom{N-1}{M-1}-1}.
$$

Now, whenever $p$ and $q$ are integers with $p\neq 0$ and $q>0$ we have $\left\lceil \frac{p}q\right\rceil=\left\lfloor\frac{p-1}q\right\rfloor + 1$.
Letting $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$ denote the fractional part of $x$, we see that

$$\left\lceil \frac{N}M\right\rceil-1
=
\left(\frac{N}M-1\right)
+
\left(1-\frac1M-\left\{\frac{N-1}M\right\}\right)$$

Then the inequality above can be rewritten as

$$T\leq \left(\frac{N}M-1\right)-\underbrace{\frac{1-\frac1M-\left\{\frac{N-1}M\right\}}{\binom{N-1}{M-1}-1}}_{(*)}$$

and $(*)$ should generally be a tiny number, since the numerator lies in $\big(-\frac1M,1-\frac1M\Big]$.
A perhaps decent approximation is hence $T\leq\left\lceil\frac{N}M\right\rceil-1$.